# moving a large table into separate database

Tags: mysql, database, chat

I have a project which has MYSQL database of around 20 tables. the growth of data in these tables are normal.
EXCEPT for one table will increase so fast and expected to be huge comparing to the other tables.

The project is a platform that provide services and having instant chat between clients. and the chat feature is used intensively.
The large table is the messages table.

In terms of best practices, should I keep the database as is or should I use 2 separate databases, one is dedicated to the chat feature, and another database for the project ?

I have afraid that this huge table will affect the performance of the project

Comment: When you say huge, what does that mean? By 2024 end, do you expect it to have 100K records, 500K, 1MM, 50MM, 100MM, 500MM, or 1B+ records? There are tradeoffs with different storage methods and they depend on your use cases.

Comment: what are the datypes of the columns?

Comment: And when you say "database" do you mean in the same MySQL instance, in a separate schema, or do you mean in a second MySQL instance on a different server? If the former, it's not likely to make any difference, because MySQL Server uses the same resources for all tables in the same instance, regardless of which schema they're in.

Comment: Hmmm, if you are asking for pointers, I would develop your chat application using web sockets for real time user experience. Then at the end of that chat session, the entire chat log is saved as one record. This prevents you adding a record for each message that is sent multiplied by N amount of users.

Comment: @suchislife - That sounds like the same table size, just fewer but bigger rows.

Comment: If you do not yet grasp the relevance of managing an entire chat session with a single unique id vs a record for each message in that session, I would start there first.

Answer (score 2):

If, by "database", you mean "server", you are asking for a lot of hassle and sluggishness.

If, by "database", you mean `CREATE DATABASE`, there is no performance advantage in how `TABLEs` are distributed among the databases.  I like to put separate applications in separate databases.  You seem to have only one application.

It is somewhat common to have one table that dominates.  There could be issues with that table's size.  Will you be purging "old" data eventually?  If so, consider [*Partitioning*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint) .  If you have performance issues, you may need to have better `INDEXes`; let's see the slowest queries.  For example, the `PRIMARY KEY` should probably *start* with either the `chat_id` or the pair of `user_ids`.  Let's see `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for further discussion.